# Finding if a number is a perfect square using maths trickery

Tags: python

First post here;

I'm trying to find if an inputted number is a perfect square. This is what i've come up with (im a complete first timer noob)

```
import math

num = int(input("enter the number:"))

square_root = math.sqrt(num)
perfect_square = list[1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 00]
ldigit = num%10

if ldigit in perfect_square:
     print(num, "Is perfect square")
```

The list are digits that if the integer ends in, it will be a perfect square.

```
perfect_square = list[1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 00]

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Never seen this before (surprise). Apologies if it's a total mess of logic and understanding.

Comment: Parentheses, not square brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
perfect_square = list[1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 00]
```

Should be:

```
perfect_square = ['1', '4', '5', '6', '9', '00']
```

Secondly these are defined as ints, so you cannot have a number 00, instead convert everything to string to do the check and then back to ints with `str` and `int`.

Personally I'd rather go with another approach:

```
import math

num = int(15)
square_root = math.sqrt(num)

if square_root == int(square_root):
    print(f"{num} is a perfect square")
else:
    print(f"{num} is not a perfect square")
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a list without the keyword 'list', like this:

```
perfect_square = [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 00]
```

Comment: This won't completely solve the problem as he can't test against 00 (which becomes 0) in the array.

Answer (score 0):

We dont need list keyword in order to create List object in python .

List is a python builtin type.  List literals are written within square brackets [].

For Example :
 squares = [1, 4, 9, 16]

squares is a List here .

Ashutosh